# Excel VSTO Custom task Pane availability

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I writting an Excel application-level VSTO. But there is something I do not understand. The custom ribbon tab I created is available at the application level, meaning for all opened workbooks.

I created the ribbon tab using the **Ribbon Designer** and I call an instance of it through a function `setRibbonControlState` in the `ThisAddIn.cs` file. The function is called by the 3 events I handle from the `ThisAddIn_startup`:

```
((Excel.AppEvents_Event)Application).NewWorkbook += new Excel.AppEvents_NewWorkbookEventHandler(App_NewWorkbook);
Application.WorkbookBeforeClose += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(App_WorkbookBeforeClose);
Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(App_NewWorkbook);
```

At this level, everything works fine.

Then I created 3 User Tab Controls (with a `.cs` file for each of course) to display in 3 CustomTaskPanes. I created the 3 CustomTaskPanes in the `load` event handler of the ribbon tab and wrote functions to display the appropriate Task Pane and the appropriate Tab of the inner control. Here is a partial code of the ribbon.cs, showing how I created and display the CustomTaskPane:

```
private CustomTaskPane tsPane;

    private void tsFinStRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        // Custom task pane
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsDataControl(), "Data", Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow);
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsStControl(), "Statements", Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow);
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsPubControl(), "Publishing", Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow);
        tsPane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
        tsPane.Visible = false;
    }

    // Données
    private tsDataControl setDataPane()
    {
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[0];
        tsDataControl control = tsPane.Control as tsDataControl;

        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Etats
    private tsStControl setStPane()
    {
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[1];
        tsStControl control = tsPane.Control as tsStControl;

        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Publications
    private tsPubControl setPubPane()
    {
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[2];
        tsPubControl control = tsPane.Control as tsPubControl;

        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Balance générale
    private void tsBtn1A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsDataControl control = setDataPane();
            control.selectTab(0);
        }
    }

    // balance tiers
    private void tsBtn1B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsDataControl control = setDataPane();
            control.selectTab(1);
        }
    }

    // Calcul des états
    private void tsBtn2A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(0, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Calcul des états avec notes annexes
    private void tsBtn2A1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(0, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Calcul des états sans notes annexes
    private void tsBtn2A2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(0, btnId);
        }
    }

    // Bilan
    private void tsBtn2B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Bilan actif
    private void tsBtn3A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Bilan Passif
    private void tsBtn3B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }
```

When I open Excel, I can access the appropriate task pane and tab in the inner control only from the initial spreadsheet. Any further spreadsheet I open or create provides the ribbon tab but when I click on any of its button, the custom task panes do not show up.

I tried to created the tasks panes from the `ThisAddIn.cs` file, and it effectively creates them, but they react only when I click on the ribbon from the initial spreadsheet.

In my reading, I could not find a way to efficiently attach the ribbon to the tasks panes to make it behave correctly.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Thank.

**EDIT**

Here is the complete `ThisAddIn.cs` code:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Events handlers
        ((Excel.AppEvents_Event)Application).NewWorkbook += new Excel.AppEvents_NewWorkbookEventHandler(App_NewWorkbook);
        Application.WorkbookBeforeClose += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(App_WorkbookBeforeClose);
        Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(App_NewWorkbook);
    }

    private void setRibbonControlState(ref bool isEnabled)
    {
        int workbookCount = Application.Windows.Count;
        if (workbookCount > 1 && !isEnabled)
            return;

        tsFinStRibbon ribbon = Globals.Ribbons.tsFinStRibbon;
        int tabCount = ribbon.Tabs.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++)
        {
            RibbonTab tab = ribbon.Tabs[i];
            int grpCount = tab.Groups.Count;

            for (int j = 0; j < grpCount; j++)
            {
                RibbonGroup grp = tab.Groups[j];
                int itCount = grp.Items.Count;

                for (int k = 0; k < itCount; k++)
                {
                    grp.Items[k].Enabled = isEnabled;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isEnabled)
        {
            int paneCount = CustomTaskPanes.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < paneCount; i++)
                CustomTaskPanes[i].Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void App_NewWorkbook(Excel.Workbook Wb)
    {
        // Set the ribbon
        bool isEnabled = true;
        setRibbonControlState(ref isEnabled);
    }

    private void App_WorkbookBeforeClose(Excel.Workbook Wb, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        bool isEnabled = (Cancel) ? false : true;
        setRibbonControlState(ref isEnabled);
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the complete `tsFinRibbon.cs` code:

```
public partial class tsFinStRibbon
{
    //static private Dictionary<string, CustomTaskPane> tsDPanes = new Dictionary<string, CustomTaskPane>();
    private CustomTaskPane tsPane;

    private void tsFinStRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        // Custom task pane
        Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsDataControl(), "Data");
        Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsStControl(), "Statements");
        Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsPubControl(), "Publishing");
    }

    // Data task pane call
    private tsDataControl setDataPane()
    {
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[0];
        tsDataControl control = tsPane.Control as tsDataControl;

        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Statement task pane call
    private tsStControl setStPane()
    {
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[1];
        tsStControl control = tsPane.Control as tsStControl;

        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Publications task pane call
    private tsPubControl setPubPane()
    {
        tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[2];
        tsPubControl control = tsPane.Control as tsPubControl;

        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Balance générale
    private void tsBtn1A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsDataControl control = setDataPane();
            control.selectTab(0);
        }
    }

    // balance tiers
    private void tsBtn1B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsDataControl control = setDataPane();
            control.selectTab(1);
        }
    }

    // Calcul des états
    private void tsBtn2A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(0, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Calcul des états avec notes annexes
    private void tsBtn2A1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(0, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Calcul des états sans notes annexes
    private void tsBtn2A2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(0, btnId);
        }
    }

    // Bilan
    private void tsBtn2B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Bilan actif
    private void tsBtn3A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Bilan Passif
    private void tsBtn3B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Bilan N-1
    private void tsBtn3C_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Haut du bilan
    private void tsBtn3D_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Bas du bilan
    private void tsBtn3E_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(1, btnId);
        }
    }

    // Compte de résultat
    private void tsBtn2C_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(2, btnId);
        }
    }

    // -- Compte de résultat charges
    private void tsBtn4A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(2, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn4B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(2, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn4C_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(2, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn4D_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(2, btnId);
        }
    }

    // Flux de trésorerie
    private void tsBtn2D_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(3, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn5A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(3, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn5B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonButton btn = (RibbonButton)sender as RibbonButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(3, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn5C_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(3, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn5D_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(3, btnId);
        }
    }

    // Annexes
    private void tsBtn6A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsStControl control = setStPane();
            RibbonSplitButton btn = (RibbonSplitButton)sender as RibbonSplitButton;
            string btnId = btn.Name;
            control.selectTab(4, btnId);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn7A_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsPubControl control = setPubPane();
            control.selectTab(0);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn7B_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsPubControl control = setPubPane();
            control.selectTab(1);
        }
    }

    private void tsBtn7C_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count != 0)
        {
            tsPubControl control = setPubPane();
            control.selectTab(2);
        }
    }
}
```

I changed a bit the load event handler of the custom ribbon tab. The use of the `tspane` property was irrelevant. The load event handler of the custom ribbon tab creates three custom tasks panes. Each of them are related to a specific group of ribbon buttons. When a button in a group is clicked, the appropriate task pane is called and the appropriate tabControl in the task pane is activated.

As I said before, when I open Excel, only the initial workbook return the custom task pane when I click on a ribbon button.

I also noticed that when I open Excel, create/open a second workbook and click on a ribbon button of the custom ribbon tab, the task pane that is visible on the initial workbook reacts and activates the correct tab or task pane.

Comment: You don't provide sufficient information to repro what's happening in the add-in. Please include the events (with the minimal code relevant to the problem) and any other relevant information (a [mcve]). Also, what `tsFinStRibbon_Load` is doing is unclear: Why create three separate CTP and assign them to the same object `tsPane`? This is confusing, at the very least.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. Remember, if you want to inform people or answer them in comments to "ping" by using the `@` plus their name. I didn't see you'd added the requested information until checking through this morning...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out finally. The Custom Task Panes must be created for each window it needs to appear on. As I thought the Custom Task Panes was bound to the application and not any specific Workbook, I just created the 3 of them only once.

So, I created a Dictionary to keep track of the Task Panes I creates and its position in the CustomTaskPaneCollection so I can recall / or create (if necessary) any Task Pane when I switch Excel windows. Here are the key codes:

```
    private CustomTaskPane tsPane;
    private int Wn;
    private Dictionary<string, int> dict;

    private void tsFinStRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a dictionary of indexes
        dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }
    // Données
    private tsDataControl setDataPane()
    {
        // Initialize the window ID and pane name
        Wn = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd;
        string paneName = "Data" + Wn.ToString();

        // Check if the CTP already exists and create it otherwise
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(paneName))
        {
            tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsDataControl(), paneName);
            dict.Add(paneName, Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[dict[paneName]];
        }

        // Get the tab control
        tsDataControl control = tsPane.Control as tsDataControl;

        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Etats
    private tsStControl setStPane()
    {
        // Initialize the window ID and pane name
        Wn = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd;
        string paneName = "Statement" + Wn.ToString();

        // Check if the CTP already exists and create it otherwise
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(paneName))
        {
            tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsStControl(), "Statement");
            dict.Add(paneName, Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[dict[paneName]];
        }

        // Get the tab control
        tsStControl control = tsPane.Control as tsStControl;

        // Display the pane
        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }

    // Publications
    private tsPubControl setPubPane()
    {
        // Initialize the window ID and pane name
        Wn = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd;
        string paneName = "Publishing" + Wn.ToString();

        // Check if the CTP already exists and create it otherwise
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(paneName))
        {
            tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new tsPubControl(), paneName);
            dict.Add(paneName, Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Count - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            tsPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes[dict[paneName]];
        }

        // Get the tab control  
        tsPubControl control = tsPane.Control as tsPubControl;

        // Display the pane
        if (!tsPane.Visible)
        {
            tsPane.Width = 320;
            tsPane.Visible = true;
        }

        return control;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: By "Excel Window", do you mean Workbook, Worksheet, other?