# Should a parent window be assigned to a custom task pane for a VSTO for Excel Add-in?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am developing a VSTO add-in for Excel in Visual Studio 2019 in C#.

I am closely following the Microsoft docs at these links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-synchronizing-a-custom-task-pane-with-a-ribbon-button?view=vs-2019

- My custom ribbon works without issue.
- The task pane is instantiated but never visible.
- I can programmatically set the task pane Visible property.  This has no effect.
- The custom task pane is created and the programmatic state of the task pane's visibility property can be displayed on the custom ribbon bar.
- I have stripped all COM+ and Excel Add-ins from Excel.
- "Display all Application Add-ins" is checked in the Excel Trust Center.
- I am using the overloaded `Add` method that accepts a `Window` parameter. The `Window` parameter specifies the window that the custom task pane is associated with.  I have tried assigning this to the Active Workbook.  This has no effect.

The code that I am using to instantiate the custom task pane is below.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            

            // Help Task Pane
            helpTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(helpControl, 
                                                    "EMPHelpPane",
                                                     Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook);

            helpTaskPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;
            helpTaskPane.Width = 500;
            helpTaskPane.Height = 500;
            


            helpTaskPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
            helpTaskPane.Width = 300;

            helpTaskPane.Visible = true;
            
            // Help Pane Events
            helpTaskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(HelpTaskPaneVisibleChanged);
            helpTaskPane.DockPositionChanged += HelpTaskPane_DockPositionChanged;
        }
```

I am wondering if this is a parent window issue.  The stackoverflow post below kind-of confirms this - however, they are creating a custom task pane when an "Excel Window" is created.  I do not see any code that assigns a parent window to a custom task pane.

*I think "Excel Window" in the post below means Worksheet.  But, I am not sure.*

[Excel VSTO Custom task Pane availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908139/excel-vsto-custom-task-pane-availability)

Items that I will try next:

- I have derived a custom class that implements the CustomTaskPane interface and have made the `Window` property read-write.
- A number of posts use a `Dictionary` to track active tack panes and the Window that each is associated with.  I am creating a class derived from a Dictionary to keep up with the custom task panes.
- I will try associating the CustomTaskPane with different types of "Excel Windows".
- Investigate switching to a commercial off-the-shelf Excel compatible control.

Comment: did you check that the taskpane width is not 0? Also, by Excel Window, I don't think this would refer to the Worksheet. The Window might refer to the `Application.Window` object... or perhaps even the windows handler, which can be referenced by `Application.Hwnd`

Comment: Hi ArcherBird - the custom pane width is programmatically set to 300.  Additionally, I have tried changing the docking position.  This has no effect on the visibility of the pane.

Comment: could you show your code for how your task pane is initialized?

Comment: Hi ArcherBird - I will post the code this evening.

Comment: Hi ArcherBird - apologies for the delay in adding the code.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the .add method call, change ActiveWorkbook into ActiveWindow